# Java string comparison with equals() not working as expected with UDP

Tags: java, string, udp

I am trying to send a message over UDP and comparing it with a string literal, but it does not seem to work.

Here is the UDP server code

```
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class Controller {

    public static void main(String args[]) {


        //create UDP server
        try {
            DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(5002);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);

            //wait for done message
            socket.receive(packet);
            String msg = new String (packet.getData());
            if(msg.equals("Done"))
            {
                System.out.println("Done received");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Done not received");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the UDP client code

```
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class Slave {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        //create UDP client
        try {
            DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
            byte[] buffer;

            //send Done message
            buffer = "Done".getBytes();
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 5002);
            socket.send(packet);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

The output I get is "done not received", even though done message is sent. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: If you are not receiving the word Done on the end then how can you confirm it is in fact being sent correctly? What did you actually receive in your msg variable?

Comment: What does `msg` contain ?

Comment: You sent only however many bytes are in `Done`, yet you always receive 1024 byets. It might be the reason behind your failure, but without you debugging this more closely, it's hard to tell. At least add a `println` after you have constructed a string you've received, to see what did you actually receive.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Thanks. I actually do check the message in my code. I just kept the bare minimum when posting the question. It did seem like "Done" is what is sent as when I print the string, only Done is printed.

Comment: @csm_dev I did receive only Done, or that is what I thought because after printing the message I got only Done as output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is, that you are declaring a buffer with 1024 bytes, which you are the converting to a string. That string does not equal "Done", it is simply "too long". You have to obtain the actual length of your sent data. You could do something like this in your `Controller`:

```
public class Controller {

    public static void main(String args[]) {


        //create UDP server
        try {
            DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(5002);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);

            //wait for done message
            socket.receive(packet);

            //Get actual data length and copy it
            byte[] data = new byte[packet.getLength()];
            System.arraycopy(packet.getData(), packet.getOffset(), data, 0, packet.getLength());

            //Create string from actual data
            String msg = new String (data);
            if(msg.equals("Done"))
            {
                System.out.println("Done received");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Done not received");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
String msg = new String(packet.getData(), packet.getOffset(), packet.getLength());
```

`DatagramPacket` contains other information such as the port and host. Calling `new String()` on the data will extract more information than just the data message. Using `packet.getData()` and setting the offset will make sure that you extract just the data in the packet and leave out the port and host.

See [the JavaDocs for DatagramPacket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/DatagramPacket.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

When I debug your code, I can see that the message is "Done" with a lot of following '\u0000' which seems to be a unicode represantation of 0

So you either remove the zeros or you change your if statement to

`msg.startsWith("Done")`

Comment: But then it would print "Done received" even if the message was something like "Done...".

Comment: which is the intention I guess, could not see that the author tries to print the message. Instead he just want to ensure, that the message is arrived, or not?

Comment: And from a security perspective, this may be an opening, since you're not keeping the "real" data explicitly separate from the metadata (specifically, the \u0000 that specifies message length). What if a hacker sends a message that contains a \u0000 in an effort to fool the receiver? In this small example, that may not be so bad; but in a production app, it could be.

Comment: lol got a downvote for this? really? .... it was clear on a first glance, that this is not production code. In this case I would have said, don't write your own implementation of a UDP Server ... The question was equals() is not working so I tried to answer it

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but it could be that they were unsatisfied that you didn't give the _reason_ for the \u0000s (as the accepted answer did), and thus encouraged the OP to essentially put a band-aid on a problem without understanding its fundamental cause. (Also, \u0000 is not the code point for the char `0`, though it's unclear if that's what you meant. It's the code point for [the null character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character), which is a special, control character.)

Comment: Thx for clarification. I was never in doubt, that the accepted answer is the better one. I was just surprised about the downvote. So I will try to be more precise next time